# How can I add shapes above a text in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: open-source, libreoffice

I would like to add shapes in LibreOffice above a text like in this book page:

[image]

There is a panel for drawing stuff (View -> Toolbars -> Drawing) but even if I draw a circle or something above a text what guarantee that the shapes line up at the same level. Is there something that position the drawed shapes relative to the text below them?

If you were to write a similar document how would you do that? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways. You could use a table without borders to put content on a certain position. To "bind" an image to a word, the [anchoring settings](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Positioning_Objects) should do the trick. You can modify the anchoring on the `Type` tab of the image's properties:

[image]

With the settings shown above, the image is anchored to a certain character in the text (`Anchor` property set `To character`). The `Position` property sets the exact position of the picture relative to that character, for example. In my example, the picture appears ca. 2 cm above the character it's bound to; if the character moves, the picture will follow.